# Undelete question 4650?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I wrote a five-minute answer to this while disconnected, during which time the author deleted the question. Discard my answer or undelete and post? Not a big deal to me either way.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/how-to-compute-the-chebyshev-polynomial-expansion-of-a-function

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP deleted it... it seems to be a legitamate question...  If no one else has any objections, I'll undelete it.

Comment: I'm not sure either, I'll ping Victor via email.

Comment: I deleted it because the solution is actually in Numerical Recipes in C. I just had no idea what to look for. Feel free to undelete it.

Comment: That's fine, it doesn't matter to me. My answer was primarily the connection to _nodal_ Chebyshev bases which are more practical than _modal_ bases for most purposes.

Comment: Why delete a question for which you found the answer yourself? As SciComp should (IMHO) become a resource of (good) information, legitimate questions should not be deleted. When you find the answer yourself, just post it.

Answer (score 2):

In the rare case that one has worked up an answer, only to find the OP has deleted what seems to be a legitimate question, the possibility exists of rewriting and posting the question oneself.

The OP may have legitimate reasons for deleting, and I'd err on the side of privacy by not inquiring too closely into the reasons.  The only caveat I can think of is where the question might be part of some online competition (or homework), but many times legitimate questions will be too unpolished to be that kind.

Here the circumstance turned out somewhat differently.  Not everyone realizes that self-answering of questions is legitimate here, and of course my suggestion emphasizes this fact.